# How to migrate KVM virtual Machine

Tags: kvm-virtualization

My physical server ubuntu 8.04 server which host 4 virtual machine is have the problem with the libvirt daemon...and I can not start all 4 virtual machine, I have the other spare host which is running ubuntu 10.04 ... Can I copy the virtual machine setting .xml in /etc/libvirt/qemu and the disk image .img of the Virtual Server into the new server ? Is there any way on how to do it ?

thank folks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it will work

Comment: Awesome reply! Simple, but correct :)